# Using Postmaster to Auto Send total amount sold of an item

Tags: expresso-store, postmaster

So we're looking to use Postmaster to auto send emails to specified emails of the amount of an item total sold.  Does anyone have any idea what code we should use for this?  I've tried a few different things and haven't been able to figure it out.

I have the channel set to the correct channel that stores our products.  What would be the code to show the total sold for the selected Parse Entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to email me at support@objectivehtml.com so I can get you in the right direction. Sounds like you are trying do something a little outside the scope of the Parcels API and more in line with notifications or hooks. Without knowing more information and specific details, I can't help much more. I think though that emailing my support channel will be a better place to converse than here until we can figure out a formal solution.